# PHP Insert. How to check if its valid or not?

Tags: php, html, select, web, insert

I got this PHP Page.
The problem is:
It's not checking if **account** or **character name** is valid.

PS.: Account is a column of table accounts Character name is a column of table players

How can I check it?

```
<?php
    function anti_injection($sql)
    {
        $sql = preg_replace(sql_regcase("/(from|select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables|#|\*|--|\\\\)/"),"",$sql);
        $sql = trim($sql);
        $sql = strip_tags($sql);
        $sql = addslashes($sql);
        return $sql;
    }

    $accountorname = anti_injection($_POST['accountorname']);
    $gamecode = $_POST['gamecode'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $premiumpoints = anti_injection($_POST['premiumpoints']);

    switch ($category) {
        case 'accountname':
            $insertquery = "INSERT INTO gamecodes (gamecode, accountname, premium_points, alreadyused) VALUES ('$gamecode','$accountorname',$premiumpoints,'N')";
            break;
        case 'charactername':
            $insertquery = "INSERT INTO gamecodes (gamecode, accountname, premium_points, alreadyused) 
                    SELECT '$gamecode',accounts.name,$premiumpoints,'N' 
                    FROM accounts 
                    JOIN players
                    ON accounts.id = players.account_id 
                    WHERE players.name = '$accountorname'";
            break;
    }

    $result = mysql_query($insertquery);
?>
```

I need your help :)

Comment: and what is "valid" ?

Comment: You don't need that `anti_injection` function, you can just use some built-in function (e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php ).

Comment: oh your anti_injection() is a a joke, wont work, and lilly to cause problems

Comment: Yeah, this is way too complicated. Just use mysqli prepared statements.

Comment: Can you guys help me to check if result is valid?
And which function of PHP can I use to change my antisql?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by valid?

Comment: Did user writed valid Account or Character Name?

Comment: do you mean check they are in database? or conform to some structure?

Comment: Is in DB writed Account or Character Name? If NOT then result error. If it's there then execute mysql query

Comment: Should we use our crystal ball to get to know what in your project a valid account is? An account name that exists in another table? Then just select `COUNT(*)` from the other table with a `WHERE account =$account`.

Comment: it should not take this many comments for the op to finally explain what he wants.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to explain it:
Account is a column of table accounts Character name is a column of table players

Answer (score 1):

### Checking account and character

> It's not checking if account or character name is valid.

**character name**

Your already checking via `switch ($category)` whether the `$category` is `'accountname'` or `'charactername'`. The only thing remaining is to output an error message if it is not one of these.

**account name**

1) I imagine account name is a value you insert that actually is a foreign key within the `gamecodes` table and maps to an `accounts` table or something similar.

The easiest thing you can do is simply use `referential integrity` in creating your tables. Define the relationships between your tables, and if the `account name` is invalid the query will fail.

2) Another option is to perform a select statement using the `account name` and verify that the `account` exists within another table. Additionally, you may do further checks using PHP.

### In Relation to API

`MySQL_*` functions are deprecated. You should check out alternatives such as Mysqli, and PDOs. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: omg sorry.
Account is a column of table accounts
Character name is a column of table players

Answer (score 1):

It's awesome that you are thinking along the right lines here. SQL injection is probably the number 1 cause of websites being hacked. There are really a few steps to ensureing things are good from simple to pretty simple they look like this:

**Simple things**

Any variable that the user supplies (e.g. $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, $_SERVER or anywhere else) shouldn't be trusted.

If you are using mysql_*, then ensuring you do one of the following will be good in 90% of cases:

```
 $safe_number = (int)$_GET['number']; // forces safe_number to be an integer
```

and

```
 $safe_string = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['string']); // ensure that the string doesn't have any characters in that will trip up mysql.
```

**Slightly more complex things**

Use prepared statements for SQL. The mysql_* functions (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) are used by lots of people, and really are not good because they don't support prepared statements.

You should read http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php and use this instead. In short, you tell mysql, 'Hey, this variable is an integer', and mysql deals with that for you.

Many people recommend using PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) because it lets you easily work with different databases to mysql if required.

Whatever – mysqli or PDO, just not mysql_*.

Answer (score 0):

**accountname** and **charactername** are already 'verified' in the sense that the cases are only taken if the switch matches these literals.

Knowing that SQL injection needs to be defended against is good, however, the solution actually implemented isn't - the input **gamecode** for example, is a gaping hole. You should ideally use prepared statements. [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php%20mysqli_real_escape_string) or equivalents are workable as well, but there are caveats regarding the default server character set you should be aware of.

Lastly, as far as possible, make sure the input you get is input you expect with something like [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php%20preg_match). For example, if **gamecode** can only be a 6-digit integer, you could do

```
if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{6}$/', $gamecode) === 0){
    // fail
}
```

Comment: GameCode field cant be writed, it's READONLY.
Now I'm using mysql_real_escape_string.
I must Know now if writed accountname and/or character name exist in database